# Keep Fragment state when switching tabs

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 4 tabs A, B, C and D. I want to keep previous tab view. Ex:Tab A (Default) -> B  -> A. When returning to tab A, I want tab A 's views to be the same as before

[image: Graph: Fragment A (or B or C or D) on top of 4 tabs (A, B, C, D)]

Here is my code:

```
private void replaceFragment(Constants.BottomTab bottomTab) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(bottomTab.getValue());
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (fragment == null) {
        switch (bottomTab) {
            case A:
                fragment = new A();
                break;
            case B:
                fragment = new B();
                break;
            case C:
                fragment = new C();
                break;
            case D:
                fragment = new D();
                break;
        }
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment,bottomTab.getValue() );
        transaction.addToBackStack(bottomTab.getValue()); // Tag
        transaction.commit();
        Log.v(">>>", "Create fragment: " + fragment.getTag());
    } else { // pop from stack
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment, bottomTab.getValue());
        transaction.commit();
        Log.v(">>>", "Found fragment: " + fragment.getTag());
    }
}
```

Tab A keep recreating when I switch to it from tab B

I know another approach is using `ViewPager` and `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4)` but what is the solution to my code above?

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can propose a possible solution, use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter but disable swipe.

Answer (score 0):

As simple solution I can suggest you to hold references to those fragment and create each of them only if they are null. So it could be like this:

```
private Fragment aFrag;
private Fragment bFrag;
private Fragment cFrag;
private Fragment dFrag;

private void replaceFragment(Constants.BottomTab bottomTab) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(bottomTab.getValue());
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (fragment == null) {
        switch (bottomTab) {
            case A:
                if (aFrag == null) aFrag = new A();
                fragment = aFrag;
                break;
            case B:
                if (bFrag == null) bFrag = new B();
                fragment = bFrag;
                break;
            case C:
                if (cFrag == null) cFrag = new C();
                fragment = cFrag;
                break;
            case D:
                if (dFrag == null) dFrag = new D();
                fragment = dFrag;
                break;
        }
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment,bottomTab.getValue() );
        transaction.addToBackStack(bottomTab.getValue()); // Tag
        transaction.commit();
        Log.v(">>>", "Create fragment: " + fragment.getTag());
    } else { // pop from stack
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment, bottomTab.getValue());
        transaction.commit();
        Log.v(">>>", "Found fragment: " + fragment.getTag());
    }
}
```